# Application of primary decomposition theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials, invariant-subspace

Suppose we have a linear map  $T:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$  whose minimal polynomial is $m_T(x)= x^2+1$. We cannot apply the primary decomposition theorem to give non-trivial T-invariant subspaces, since the roots are imaginary.

Does this allow us to conclude that there are no non-trivial T-invariant subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$ or does it only mean that we cannot apply the primary decomposition theorem and that non-trivial T-invariant subspaces can still be found by a more direct approach (i.e. by using matrix representation of T to find which lines are invariant)?

Many thanks.

Comment: It might help if you said what you understand by the primary decomposition theorem. I say this because I don't know why you think it tells you about all the invariant subspaces in general. For example, suppose $T$ is on a $10$-dim space and $M_T=X^4$. There are many possibilities for the pattern of invariant subspaces. I think you  need to team the PDTh with the Rational Canonical Form to tell the whole story in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $U$ is non-trivial T-invariant subspace. Then $\dim U =1$, hence there is $x_0 \ne 0$ such that $U = span \{x_0\}.$

From $T(x_0) \in U$ we get some $ \lambda \in \mathbb R$ with $T(x_0)= \lambda x_0.$

But then $ \lambda $ is an eigenvalue of $T$, hence $\lambda = \pm i,$ a contradiction.